# QML and QThread multithreading

Tags: javascript, multithreading, qml, qthread

I use a class

```
class DesktopFileScanner : public QThread 
{ 
void scan() { start(QThread::HighPriority)); }
void run() { /* the scanning instructions here*/}
/**/ 
};
```

to perform time consuming (~2 sec) operations. I'd like to show a busy indicator while the scanner is doing this. The busy indicator is called

```
ind
```

The qml Sheet has this property:

```
Component.onCompleted:
{
    scanner.scan() // scanner is an instance of DesktopFileScanner
    ind.visible = false
}
```

This way the indicator becomes invisible before scanner finishes scanning.
How can I fix it so that

```
ind.visible = false
```

will be called after scanner thread is finished (scanner finishes scanning)

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connections item in QML can be used

```
Component.onCompleted:
{
    scanner.scan()
}

Connections
{
    target: scanner
    onFinished: ind.visible = false
}
```